# Find number of occurrences and number of lines the value is in on a text file?

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

*The scope of the problem is this:*

**Search an array of string type for a value of string type that was read in from a text file and print the number of occurrences and print the number of lines that keyword occurs in.**

The expected output is:

```
Keyword: union

Total # of keyword occurrences: 87
Total # of lines with occurrences: 29
```

*The function I have written for this is below.*

```
void search(int IDs[], string posts[], int size)
{
    string keyword = "";
    int postCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    bool found = false;
    cout << "Enter keyword: " << endl;
    cin >> keyword;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        while((pos >= 0 && pos <= size))
        {
            pos = posts[i].find(keyword,pos);
            lineCount++;
            pos++;

        }
        if((pos >= 0 && pos <= size-1))
        {
            postCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total # of Occurances: " << lineCount + postCount << endl;
    cout << "Total # of Posts: " << postCount << endl;
}
```

I ran the code above and got the output below:

```
Keyword: union

Total # of keyword occurrences: 1
Total # of lines with occurrences: 0
```

I asked my professor multiple times on what to do, and he told me that I must find the keyword in each line and then start at the `pos+1` in the line to continue to find the next occurrences efficiently and keep track of how many times I "find" the keyword, and if I do not find it then do not count the line at all.

Comment: "I asked my professor multiple times on what to do, and he told me that I must find the keyword in each line and then start at the pos+1 in the line to continue to find the next occurrences..." Sounds like good advice :)  Your code doesn't match your output, so we're not sure where you're "stuck".  SUGGESTION: check for "not found" inside your while loop...

Comment: Use getline to read a file line by line.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I already read the file. I am searching the array of strings now.

Comment: If you used getline instead you could have broken it down using split and then did a count.I have no idea how your array of strings will know it's the next line.

Comment: each call of find returns one of two values ... you seem to be ignoring (not handling) one of them.

Comment: @2785528 find returns either string::npos or -1 for Mac and it returns the position of keyword that is found.

Comment: so, where (in your code) do you handle npos?

Comment: @2785528 while the pos is between any valid points we continue to find the the keyword in the line. the pos starts at 0, and it will be -1 if not found Mac OS X and then it will NOT satisfy that while loop anymore.

Comment: It looks like if a line does not have the keyword (at all), pos is assigned npos.  So, where does pos reset to 0 when your for loop steps to the next element of posts?

Comment: @2785528 Let me try to edit the code to see if that will work. I will let you know.

Comment: @2785528 I get wrong output, I attempt to find in the while loop condition and it returns the wrong output. I find the keyword 56 times, it is wrong.

Comment: Your 'find' statement triggers 2 warnings.  Add -Wconversion and -Wsign-conversion to your compile, then solve the warnings.

Comment: [MCVE] 's should compile.  does this post compile?

Comment: Did you find, in your code snippet, where 'pos' is reset to 0 for each strring (of posts) to be searched?  A 'patch' to try might be to add to the bottom of the 'for loop':  pos = 0;

Comment: FYI:  From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos:  "Although the definition uses -1, size_type is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, ..."

Comment: Because of its placement in the function parameters, I would guess that 'size' is the c-style number of element in 'posts'.   Thus, the first for-loop (where size is first used) is apparently stepping through the elements of posts.  HOWEVER, pos, set by find, is used as an index into a single element, so there, 'size' (the array size) is misapplied as if it was the element size.   I think these mistakes would have been avoided by using C++ "vector<string> posts;", then no parameter 'size' is needed (by using posts.size()), and the confusion with string length could have been avoided.

Comment: @2785528 Yeah I was using the wrong size variable.